# List LocalDate rest spring serialize

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, localdate

I have a response of `List<LocalDate>`
My Class

```
public class CompetenciaAbertaResponseDTO 
    private List<LocalDate> competencias = new ArrayList<>();
```

and response JSON

```
{
  "competencias": [
    {
      "year": 2022,
      "month": "MARCH",
      "monthValue": 3,
      "dayOfMonth": 1,
      "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
      },
      "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY",
      "leapYear": false,
      "dayOfYear": 60,
      "era": "CE"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need read this another service from `RestTemplate` in spring.
Like this

```
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
    String json = response.getBody()
    CompetenciaAbertaResponsetDTO resp =  objectMapper.readValue(json, CompetenciaAbertaResponsetDTO.class);
```

Error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

And when i change for this:

```
       this.restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(new DefaultUriBuilderFactory("http://localhost:9001")); 
        String url = RestPath.CONTABIL_FINANCEIRO_SERVICE.listaCompetenciaAbertas;
 ResponseEntity<CompetenciaAbertaResponsetDTO> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, CompetenciaAbertaResponsetDTO.class);
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class br.com.preventsenior.contasmedicas.infra.rest.client.dto.CompetenciaAbertaResponsetDTO] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Expected array or string.; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Expected array or string.
```

---

I believe it is necessary to create a serialization class. But I don't know how to do it with a List of `LocalDate`.

Can you help me please

Comment: Replace `String.class` with `CompetenciaAbertaResponsetDTO.class` and remov the objectmapper.

Comment: Doesn't work too.

Comment: How are you constructing the `RestTemplate`?  Assuming you use the `RestTemplateBuilder` it gets the configured object mapper which has the java time module attach (assuming that is on the classpath).

Comment: Return this error,: Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Expected array or string.; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Expected array or string.

Comment: The problem is that your response is already wrong. What you should send (and what normally happens if you use the regular Spring Boot setup) is that your dates get translated into an ISO date string, which can be converted back. What you have now is the internal object structure of LocalDate which basically has no meaning.

Comment: This is code for RestTemplate:        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        //restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(this.baseRestUrl));
        restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(new DefaultUriBuilderFactory("http://localhost:9001"));
        String url = RestPath.CONTABIL_FINANCEIRO_SERVICE.listaCompetenciaAbertas;
        ResponseEntity<CompetenciaAbertaResponsetDTO> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, CompetenciaAbertaResponsetDTO.class);

Comment: Please don't add code as comments, as that is totally unreadable. 1. you shouldnl't create a `RestTEmplate` like that as it will impact performance, instead create one in an `@Bean` method and use the `RestTemplateBuilder` instead of `new RestTemplate()`. 2. It is the **response** that is wrong not your code for retrieving, so you need to fix the thing that is sending this.